# Can we connect firebase database with Webflow?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, webflow

Can we connect firebase database with Webflow?
All data and pictures of the project need to be found in firebase. How can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase has a JavaScript SDK that allows you to access it from within the front-end code of any web site. So yes, you should be able to include that SDK into your HTML or build process. There is no pre-built template for this though, so you'll have to write the client-side JavaScript yourself.

Some links from [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=webflow+firebase++database&oq=webflow+firebase+database):

- very old [thread on the Webflow forums](https://forum.webflow.com/t/firebase-possibilities/2672)
- zapier has a [connector between Firebase and Webflow](https://zapier.com/apps/firebase/integrations/webflow)
- Jason Dark has a video series on [Webflow + Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30AIpEnsEaQ)

Comment: The Jason Dark tutorial worked well for me with some modifications to the code: https://medium.com/@nitin_l/firebase-auth-in-webflow-8d9d3fd50108